# Incompatible group permissions in Linux - Is it a bug?

Tags: permissions, users

I am on Ubuntu 11.04. I am creating another user and placing an existing user in the group of other user, hoping to write in the home directory of other user.

```
# uname -a
Linux vini 2.6.38-11-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 12 21:18:14 UTC
2011 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux
# whoami
sachin
# su root
# useradd -m -U foo               // create user foo
# usermod -a -G foo sachin      // add user `sachin' to group `foo'
# chmod 770 /home/foo/
# exit
# whoami
sachin
# cd /home/foo/
bash: cd: /home/foo/: Permission denied
# groups sachin
sachin : sachin foo
```

This is totally weird. Though user `sachin` is in group `foo`, and group bits for  /home/foo/ is set to rwx, `sachin` can't chdir to /home/foo/. I am not able to understand this.

But, if at the `exit` step, I switch to `sachin` user from root, this is what happens:

```
# uname -a
Linux vini 2.6.38-11-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 12 21:18:14 UTC
2011 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux
# whoami
sachin
# su root
# useradd -m -U foo               // create user foo
# usermod -a -G foo sachin      // add user `sachin' to group `foo'
# chmod 770 /home/foo/
# su sachin
# whoami
sachin
# cd /home/foo/
# ls
examples.desktop
```

Now, whatever is happening here is totally incomprehensible. Does `su sachin` inherits some permissions from the `root` user at this step?

Any explanations would be much appreciated.

Comment: It might help if you checked, in each step, the contents of `/etc/group` and did `ls -ld /home/foo` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

What are the permission of /home?  You need +x permissions there as well.

Also, you need to use `su - sachin` to get to full environment of the new user.

Note that the man page for `useradd` now says:

> ```
>    useradd is a low level utility for adding users. On Debian,
>    administrators should usually use adduser(8) instead.
> ```

If you're using a desktop/GUI version, things usually work out more easily with the `users-admin` tool.

The user with the active shell won't inherit the new group in this session (assuming you're doing it as in the example, or by script) -- you need to have a new shell for that user to test the group membership.  (Unless you are root.)  This is a longstanding Unix behavior -- so you would typically start a new shell process for the user, e.g., by opening a new terminal (which spawns a new shell, reading your environment by default), or by spawning a new shell for the user in the same terminal.

Comment: /home does have +x, 
The thing is I can't use `su - sachin` because I am creating the new users programmatically, and after that I need to access these directories via apache server which is running under `sachin` The only workout is that I access directories via c code where the setuid bit is on. But that is an overkill, keeping in mind that `sachin` is in the group of the new user and should logically have access to the new user's directory. 

The problem is not of `useradd` I tried `adduser` as well and the problem persists

Comment: It would help if you gave more of an idea of how you are doing this programmtically, since in the example in the question, you are not doing so.

Comment: Yes in the above example I am not doing so but what I intended to say is that ultimately I have to carry this task from a c program having the effective uid set to root. After I have created the user, I need to copy some files from a python program to the newly created home directory. I can't run the python program via root, I was expecting if the user under which the python program is running is also in the new users group I would have been able to copy files after having set apt permissions. But unfortunately this requires a reboot which I don't want

Answer (score 1):

Logout and then login back, it will work or you can use a new terminal (not gnome-terminal, the tty-devices).

It seems to be a bug as the requirement of this logout and login is completely unnecessary.

Comment: I know it was totally unexpected that there would be a requirement for logging in and then logging out